# How to wrap the methods of class A as the methods of class B in Python?

Tags: python, class, methods, wrapper

I have many class like `SpaceA`, `SpaceB`, `SpaceC`, and so on. These classes have some similar methods, for example `method_1`, `method_2`, ..., `method_n`. But for specific class, it maybe not been implement all the `method_i`. The following is an example:

```
import numpy as np

class SpaceA(object):
    def method_1(self, array, b, c=None):
        print('method_1', array, b, c)

    def method_2(self, array, b, c=None):
        print('method_2', array, b, c)

    def method_3(self, array, b, c=None):
        print('method_2', array, b, c)
    ... # many methods

class SpaceB(object):
    ...
    def method_1(self, array, b, c=None):
        print('method_1', array, b, c)

    def method_2(self, array, b, c=None):
        print('method_2', array, b, c)

    def method_3(self, array, b, c=None):
        print('method_2', array, b, c)
    ... # many methods
```

I want to define another class named `Function` like following:

```
class Function(np.ndarray):
    def __new__(cls, space, array=None):
        if array is None:
            self = np.zeros(100).view(cls)
        else:
            self = array.view(cls)
        self.space = space
        return self

    def method_1(self, b, c=None):
        return self.space.method_1(self, b, c=c)

    def method_2(self, b, c=None):
        return self.space.method_2(self, b, c=c)

    ... # many wrapper

A = SpaceA()
B = SpaceB()

fA = Function(A)
fB = Function(B)
```

I want to automatically wrap every `method_i` of a specific class into `Function` class, is it possible? and how?

Maybe `__metaclass__` can solve my problem, but I don't make it success.

Comment: Yes, you should be able to make your `Function` class a `proxy` and automatically forward missing method calls to its `space` member. Look up the `__getattr__` method that you can implement.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks very much for @quamrana's comment, I code a new `Function` class like following:

```
import numpy as np
from types import ModuleType

class Function(np.ndarray):

    def __new__(cls, space, dim=None, array=None):
        if array is None:
            self = space.array(dim=dim).view(cls)
        else:
            self = array.view(cls)
        self.space = space
        return self

    def index(self, i):
        return Function(self.space, array=self[:, i])

    def __call__(self, bc, index=None):
        space = self.space
        return space.value(self, bc, index=index)

    def value(self, bc, index=None):
        space = self.space
        return space.value(self, bc, index=index)

    def __getattr__(self, item):
        def wrap(func):
            def outer(*args,  **kwargs):
                val = func(self, *args, **kwargs)
                return val
            outer.coordtype = func.coordtype
            return outer 
        if hasattr(self.space, item):
            self.__dict__[item]= wrap(getattr(self.space, item))
            return self.__dict__[item]
        else:
            print('The function space has not implemented method {}'.format(item))
```

which can solve my problem exactly.